# Spark local mode in Kubernetes sometimes fail with : Invalid Spark URL

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark

I've been running a very small pyspark (3.2.0) job in kubernetes , it work in local when I run it :

- directly with DOCKER in my localhost
- in [KIND](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start/)
- in a GKE kubernetes

but in an another GKE kubernetes it fail with

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/jars/spark-unsafe_2.12-3.2.0.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
21/12/17 14:34:15 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
21/12/17 14:34:17 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Invalid Spark URL: spark://HeartbeatReceiver@XXXXX_NAME_OF_POD_XXXXXXX.2855fc:40677
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointAddress$.apply(RpcEndpointAddress.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.asyncSetupEndpointRefByURI(NettyRpcEnv.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.util.RpcUtils$.makeDriverRef(RpcUtils.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.<init>(Executor.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint.<init>(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.start(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:220)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:581)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
21/12/17 14:34:17 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread Thread-3
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.org$apache$spark$scheduler$local$LocalSchedulerBackend$$stop(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.stop(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.stop(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.stop(DAGScheduler.scala:2516)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$stop$12(SparkContext.scala:2086)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1442)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:2086)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:677)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
21/12/17 14:34:17 WARN MetricsSystem: Stopping a MetricsSystem that is not running
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 228, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 392, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 146, in __init__
    self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 209, in _do_init
    self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 329, in _initialize_context
    return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1573, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Invalid Spark URL: spark://HeartbeatReceiver@XXXXX_NAME_OF_POD_XXXXXXX.2855fc:40677
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointAddress$.apply(RpcEndpointAddress.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.asyncSetupEndpointRefByURI(NettyRpcEnv.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.util.RpcUtils$.makeDriverRef(RpcUtils.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.<init>(Executor.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint.<init>(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.start(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:220)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:581)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

the pyspark only settings :

```py
SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName(app_name) \
        .config("spark.driver.memory", "1g") \
        .config("spark.master", "local")
```

running in a docker container

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster AS py3
FROM eclipse-temurin:11-jre-focal
COPY --from=py3 / /
RUN pip install pyspark
...
```

If I add to my second kubernetes pod deployment ( the one failing ) the ENV VAR  :

```yaml
"SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME": "localhost"
```

then it work, do you have any idea why it work sometimes without ?
Thank you

Comment: Whats the difference between 2 GKE clusters? Did you create both with the same settings? Do both clusters have the same configuration? Could you also provide your permissions to both clusters?

Comment: the two GKE auto-pilot clusters have absolutely the same settings , just different names.

@kkopczak what do you mean by permissions ?

Comment: It's about this `WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred`. Later in the message, the error says you have Invalid Spark URL. Have you checked if it is as it should?